# Error in Dask connecting to HDFS

Tags: python-3.x, hdfs, anaconda, hadoop2, dask

I was trying to connect to `HDFS` using `dask`, following the [blog](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2016/02/22/dask-distributed-part-2)  then I installed the hdfs3 from the [docs](http://hdfs3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) using `conda`.
When I import the `hdfs3` it gives me an error:

> ImportError: Can not find the shared library: libhdfs3.so See
>   installation instructions at
>   http://hdfs3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

I found a [github](https://github.com/conda-forge/hdfs3-feedstock/issues/4) link but the solution specified does not work for python 3.5.2.
As the the `libprotobuf 2.5.0` is for python 2.7 and `libprotobuf 2.6.1` also doesn't work. Is there any workaround for connecting to HDFS using `dask`.
Thanks you.

Comment: Does the conversation in [this issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/hdfs3-feedstock/issues/4) help?

Comment: @MRocklin  I went through that and tried to downgrade but as I tried to install it using `pip` specifying the version it throws me an error.I'll try once again and  let you know.

Comment: @MRocklin built it from source, when I import it throws the same error.

Comment: This isn't a question of how you installed hdfs3, it's a question of whether or not your computer can find the correct libhdfs3 and libprotobuf shared libraries.  I recommend reading [this particular comment](https://github.com/conda-forge/hdfs3-feedstock/issues/4#issuecomment-242606438)

Comment: As you recommended I added an path where it could be found but still it's not finding the `libhdfs.so`. It is located in `/home/rey/anaconda3/pkgs/libhdfs3-2.2.31-1/libhdfs.so` is this the right path?

Comment: You might consider appending to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (although there are nuances to this)  This should be easier though.  This may now be resolved by https://github.com/dask/hdfs3/pull/94

Comment: @MRocklin thanks it works.

Comment: @MRocklin when I try to connect to `hdfs` kernel dies, is this an issue with `spyder` or `dask`?